# FFMPEG drawtext filter - get total width of text string so that it can start off stage

Tags: ffmpeg

I have the following FFMPEG command which simply wipes text from left to right. 
What I am trying to do is determine the total width of the text string so I can subtract this amount from the x position value, starting it off stage left. 
Since this is determined by both the font size and the actual font used I am guessing this is impossible to determine accurately...but is there a way to fudge this ?

```
ffmpeg -y -i test_small.mov -acodec libmp3lame -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -b:a 192k -b:v 1400k -ar 44100 -crf 18 -vf "drawtext=text=string1 string2 string3 string4 string5 string6 string7 :fontfile=foo.ttf: y=h-line_h-10:x=(2*n): fontcolor=white: fontsize=40: shadowx=2: shadowy=2" -an left_to_right_small.mp4
```

Comment: Note that your command uses `-an` while also specifying an audio codec. Your output will have no audio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `tw`. From the [drawtext filter documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext):

> `text_w`, `tw`
>   the width of the rendered text

Using your example you would simply add: `x=(2*n)-tw`

Comment: Duh, I was completely ignoring that for some reason.

Comment: @slhck I learn (or forget) something new with just about every question.

Comment: ditto, learn something every time I use FFMPEG